# navigate to a new fragment upon clicking on an item in listview

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, listview-adapter

so I created a listview that has 5 textviews in each row. the last textview is supposed to get me information about certain items upon being clicked. my listview's adapter has a context that corresponds to a fragment.

```
 List<itemproperties> items;
        itemdisplay context;
        public homeadapter(itemdisplay context, List<itemproperties> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
```

where itemdisplay is a fragment. and this is the code where I try to navigate to a new fragment when clicking on the textview

```
 TextView textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5);
            
            Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
            if (!textView.HasOnClickListeners)
            {
                textView.Click += (o, e) =>
                {
                    SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                            .Replace(Resource.Id.mainFrame, fragment)
                            .Commit();
                };
            }
```

all of the above codes are in my adapter. but I get an error because SupportFragmentManager doesn't seem to exist in adapters I guess. so my question is, how am I supposed to do this?
thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you Adatper need a `mainActivity` attribute in constructor, then use following way in `GetView` method.

```
   class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
    {
        private MainActivity mainActivity;
        private string[] items;

        public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, string[] items)
        {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            this.items = items;
        }

       
        public override string this[int position] => items[position];

        public override int Count => items.Length;

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = mainActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.My_textView1).Text = items[position];
            TextView textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            textView.Text = items[position];
           

            if (!textView.HasOnClickListeners)
            {
                textView.Click += (o, e) =>
                {
                    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = mainActivity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.FramePage, fragment);
                    transaction.AddToBackStack("main");
                    transaction.CommitAllowingStateLoss();
                    //  Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                };
            }


          
            return view;
        }

      
    }

   
}
```

If you transfer to fragment layout, You found the previous listview stil existed. Please add  `android:background="?android:windowBackground"` in your `activity_main.xml` and Fragment layout like following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/FramePage"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
       >
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

  </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here is my demo. you can refer to it. https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/AlertDemo.zip

Comment: thanks a lot sir. but the problem is that i'm working in a navigation drawer template. so my listview is displayed in a fragment. so my adapter's context is a fragment "itemdisplay". should I change my entire context and display my listview in an activity rather than a fragment. note that I access my listview after clicking one of my drawer's items.

Comment: ohh i'm sorry I figured out that even my fragment context has a FragmantManager. your answer was very useful sir thanks a lot